# How to get dSYM File Xcode 14.2 builds, App Store Connect no longer provides it?

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, xcode14, dsym

We are using Azure DevOps to upload our builds to TestFlight. We are using Xcode 14.2 to build our apps. Bitcode is disabled.

I can no longer download the dSYM files from iTunes connect store. Since the builds are made using Azure we do not have the archive files.

Can anyone help?